# sudo: not found on AWS Sagemaker Studio

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I was following a guide on mounting EFS in SageMaker studio, but when using the following as a notebook cell:

```
%%sh 

sudo mount -t nfs \
    -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 \
    172.31.5.227:/ \
    ../efs

sudo chmod go+rw ../efs
```

I get

```
sh: 2: sudo: not found
sh: 7: sudo: not found
```

Even in the terminal ('image terminal'), sudo is not found: `# sudo /bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get sudo working in the "System Terminal" instead. The image terminals don't seem to have access to sudo.

Unrelated: But then when I tried to mount EFS onto the SageMaker studio app, it simply failed, saying mount target is not a directory. Looks like I'm not using Sagemaker Studio this year.

Comment: How did you managed to get `sudo` working in "System Terminal"?

Comment: One way to open what Ben calls a "System Terminal" is to select "Git"->"Open Git Repository in Terminal" in SageMaker Studio.